# How to change page.url in Jekyll to actual page for the output file?

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll blog that I need to fix. Because I have this code in `_includes/head.html`:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}"/>
```

The problem is that `page.url` is `/cookies` and `/articles` for files `/cookies.md` and `/articles.md` even though the output is `/cookies.html` and `/articles.html`.

How can I change page.url to give me the actual real path to the output file?
Why I don't get html file as with the output?

I was checking my _config.yaml and I don't see anything that is relevant.

This is an old blog that I don't want to put my time into, otherwise, I would rewrite it in Eleventy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the URL using permalink:

```
---
permalink: /cookies.html
---
```